# C# Windows Forms - Using StringBuilder to generate a large string then using SendKeys to type it out. Often happening twice in one call?

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox, stringbuilder, sendkeys

I'm almost finished writing a small add-on for League of Legends that allows players to click a checkbox in my form, and the checkbox's function clicks in the search bar (which automatically clears it.  Already a feature in the LoL Client) and types out the names of all the champions the player has assigned to that group via a 2nd form.  However, if the text is (example) 12345, I've been getting a lot of results like this:  **1231234545.**

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried adding in ctrl-a + backspace with sendkeys because maybe when it clicks in the search bar it isn't always deleting the stuff there!  This however did not change anything
- I then commented out the code that types out the actual string (12345) and made the checkbox ONLY type ctrl-a.  I then wrote out a string longer than the search bar that I'm typing into and pasted it, clicked a checkbox, and tried to see if it would highlight the text (meaning the text was not always being cleared when clicked).  I did this about 50 times and every single time the text was cleared
- **This leads me to believe that the problem is in the code itself, not the actual integration with the LoL Client.**  So maybe it's a problem with StringBuilder?  I haven't used it very often so I'm not too familiar with it.  Commented out all the stringbuilder stuff and changed to String concatenation.  Same problem
- I tried adding a boolean runningCheckboxFunction to make sure the function would only run once but still have the issue as well.

So this is where I'm at right now.  I'm pretty sure it's a problem with my code looping for some reason or the checkbox function as a whole being called twice instead of once when I click the checkbox.

**My code:**

```
private void checkboxFunction()
    {
        if (runningCheckboxFunction == true) return;

        runningCheckboxFunction = true;

        //CLICK IN THE SEARCH BAR (Automatically clears the text that WAS there)
        Process[] LolClient = Process.GetProcessesByName("LolClient"); //should only return one client (i.e. get [0])
        if (LolClient.Length < 1) return;
        ClickOnPoint(LolClient[0].MainWindowHandle, searchBarCheckPoint);

        //MAKE THE STRING TO TYPE IN THE SEARCH BAR
        StringBuilder whatToTypeInSearchBar = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (CheckBox cb in checkboxes)
        {
            if (cb.Visible == true && cb.Checked == true)
            {
                List<String> thisCheckboxsChamps = settingsForm.getChampionListForGroup(checkboxes.IndexOf(cb));
                if (thisCheckboxsChamps == null) continue;
                foreach (String champ in thisCheckboxsChamps)
                {
                    whatToTypeInSearchBar.Append("|");
                    whatToTypeInSearchBar.Append(champ);
                    whatToTypeInSearchBar.Append("$");
                }
            }
        }

        //had an issue that sometimes clicking in search bar did not automatically clear it, so select all text and backspace just in case
        //^ = ctrl -- ^A = ctrl-A (select all)
        SendKeys.Send("^A");
        //backspace
        SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");

        //TYPE IN THE SEARCH BAR
        if (whatToTypeInSearchBar.Length > 0)
        {
            //remove the first "|"
            whatToTypeInSearchBar.Remove(0, 1);
            SendKeys.Send(whatToTypeInSearchBar.ToString());
        }

        runningCheckboxFunction = false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use SendWait? I rememeber it being at __little__ more reliable

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that.  Yes, I tried sendwait BEFORE i tried send actually, expecting something like this to happen and sendwait being the solution.

I also originally typed out names one at a time rather than making one big string and typing it out to avoid this too

Neither choice worked

Comment: Um, lets clear this up: Is your code actually __entering__ the if clause twice? (I mean really, not just judging from the output) If so this is the problem and has nothing to do with either stringbuilder or sendkeys.  Is there any threading/async etc involved?

Comment: Just tested and I'm pretty sure it's not actually calling the function twice.  Just had it do the issue almost every single time with half the time the reason being that it didn't delete the characters in the box (even though I have the ctrl-a + backspace code in there..), and the other half because it would only load (for example) "cian$" instead of "Lucian$"

Answer (score 0):

Which event are you using for the check box control (`CheckedChanged` or `CheckStateChanged`)? Also, what is the value for `CheckBox.ThreeState` property? It is possible that the event you use fires more than once. If that is the case, you could check for a specific state before calling the function you have listed above.

Also, when you use SendKeys, try sending the keys to your own application and monitor the `ActiveControl.KeyUp`/`ActiveControl.KeyDown`/`ActiveControl.KeyPress` events to ensure that the string you generate is the riight sequence.

Comment: I'm using CheckedChanged (the one automatically generated when you double click the Designer checkbox).  ThreeState is set to false

Can you elaborate on the ActiveControl thing?  I'm not entirely sure what you mean/how to check and make sure it's generating the right sequence

Comment: By `ActiveControl` I mean send the keys to your own app first and use a text box (for example) to catch and log the keystrokes using the `TextBox.KeyDown`/`TextBox.KeyUp`/`TextBox.KeyPress` events. That way you would be able to tell exactly what sequence you are sending to the target app.